# How to add elapsed timer (min) to GUI , during progress bar running

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

I want to add elapsed time (minutes) to an GUI and do something else in parallel.

Everything I try does not succeed, it sticks in my gui. I add example:

```
namespace Backgrondworker
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int aa = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();         
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = 0;
            progressBar1.Maximum = 10;
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {          
            for(int i =1;i<=10;i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0);            
            }          
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Value += 1;
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("completed");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Normally progress is reported via parameter of `ReportProgress` method. Are you sure event hanlders are wired? Show content of `InitializeComponent()` method.

Comment: What else do you need to do in parallel? Only the main thread can change the properties of objects on the form, so you are better doing your parallel work in a thread or task and updating the progress using a Timer control.

Comment: What *"sticks in my gui"* means? I understand it as "nothing happens", but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do the following

1. Create a Timer
2. Start the timer when you start the progress bar
3. In the timer, tick use the timespan class and Elapsed property to get the elapsed minutes and show them in a label.
4. Stop the Timer when the progressbar is at maxsize.

Answer (score 0):

You put `0` in `ReportProgress`:

```
backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0);
```

Change this to:

```
int percent = (int)Math.Round((i * 100.0) / 10);
backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(percent);
```

Dividing by `10` gives you the fraction of work done (you count `10` times in the loop) and multiplying by `100` is for getting the percent.

Answer (score 0):

I explain:
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();         
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                label2.Text = i.ToString();
            }
        });

        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                label3.Text = i.ToString();
            }
        });
    } 
}
```

got : System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'label3' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.'